# YouTube IFrame API and Angular 8 Routing Issue

Tags: angular, typescript, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I'm attempting to add the YouTube IFrame API to my application that serves videos for a course that the use is enrolled in. I have it set up so I can send my Angular application a YouTube embed code and the IFrame API will load the video correctly when I first load the course page (taken from another StackOverflow post). The problem occurs when I use router.navigate to go to a different component and then come back to the course component, the video and IFrame no longer load.

I think that when the page initially loads it creates the document object which has access to the onYouTubeIframeAPIReady method. Once I change routes, I think that previous document object is lost.

**video.component.ts:**

```js
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        const doc = (<any>window).document;
        let playerApiScript = doc.createElement('script');
        playerApiScript.type = 'text/javascript';
        playerApiScript.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
        doc.body.appendChild(playerApiScript);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        (<any>window).onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = () => {
            console.log('Ready');
            this.player = new (<any>window).YT.Player('player', {
                height: '100%',
                width: '100%',
                videoId: 'Bey4XXJAqS8',
                playerVars: {'autoplay': 0, 'rel': 0, 'controls': 2},
                events: {
                    'onReady': () => {
                    },
                    'onStateChange': () => {
                    }
                }
            });
        };
    }
```

**video.component.html**

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <div id="player" class="embed-responsive-item"></div>
</div>
```

I would like the video to re-render or stay rendered even if the user routes to a different component. Let me know if more information is needed!

Answer (score 0):

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'art-youtube-video',
  templateUrl: './youtube-video-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./youtube-video-dialog.component.scss']
})
export class YoutubeVideoDialogComponent implements OnInit {
  public YT: any;
  public video: any;
  public player: any;
  constructor() { }

  init() {
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
  }

ngOnInit() {
    this.init();
    this.video = '1cH2cerUpMQ' //video id

    window['onYouTubeIframeAPIReady'] = (e) => {
      this.YT = window['YT'];
      this.reframed = false;
      this.player = new window['YT'].Player('player', {
        videoId: this.video,
        events: {
          'onStateChange': this.onPlayerStateChange.bind(this),
          'onError': this.onPlayerError.bind(this),
          'onReady': (e) => {
            e.target.playVideo();
          }
        }
      });
    };
  }

  stopVideo() {
    this.player.stopVideo();
  }

  onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    switch (event.data) {
      case window['YT'].PlayerState.PLAYING:
        if (this.cleanTime() == 0) {
          console.log('started ' + this.cleanTime());
        } else {
          console.log('playing ' + this.cleanTime())
        };
        break;
      case window['YT'].PlayerState.PAUSED:
        if (this.player.getDuration() - this.player.getCurrentTime() != 0) {
          console.log('paused' + ' @ ' + this.cleanTime());
        };
        break;
      case window['YT'].PlayerState.ENDED:
        console.log('ended ');
        break;
    };
  };
  //utility
  cleanTime() {
    return Math.round(this.player.getCurrentTime())
  };
  onPlayerError(event) {
    switch (event.data) {
      case 2:
        console.log('' + this.video)
        break;
      case 100:
        break;
      case 101 || 150:
        break;
    };
  };

}
```

Comment: Hey man, good example, but I have a error when conect button with this.stopVideo() {
    this.player.stopVideo();
  } ....  this.player is undefinied.... =S

Comment: maybe you can try to change the player type and initialize it

Answer (score 0):

```
Example link of youtube:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=11AXUzhXK4E&t=2s
 <iframe
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/11AXUzhXK4E"
  frameborder="0"  width="800"  height="800"  allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Comment: Please explain that how your answer will help to solve the problem, and just don't give code only answer without context.

Comment: If you want to link youtube video in your project. Above code will helpful. This code is working fine in Angular 8. Just copy the code from <iframe and paste it in HTML and it will working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This happens beacuse of Once the youtube script is loaded to the angular app, then it will not reinitialize the script when we routed back. So in my case I removed those two scripts on `ngOnDestroy` and reloaded the script when component is reinitailizing.

```
const tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
tag.id = 'iframe-api-script';

const tag2 = document.createElement('script');
tag2.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/s/player/7acefd5d/www-widgetapi.vflset/www-widgetapi.js';
tag2.id = 'www-widgetapi-script';

const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
if (firstScriptTag && firstScriptTag.parentNode) {
   firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag2, firstScriptTag);
   firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
}
```

...

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    document.getElementById('www-widgetapi-script')?.remove();
    document.getElementById('iframe-api-script')?.remove();
}
```